# Exchange Calendar Concierge Rejects Invitations and Meeting updates to past appointments

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, calendar

Is there a way to configure Concierge to always accept regardless of the time of the meeting?

We need to see these updates to historic items in the shared resource calendar.